# Can't get IdentityServer4 logout to work for external (Google) authentication

Tags: identityserver4

I am working through IdentityServer4 quickstart and trying to get the external (Google) authentication to work. I am able to login through Google but after that login, even if I click Logout, I always automatically get in in the following times.

Here is the logout logic from AccountController.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Handle logout page postback
/// </summary>
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
{
    // build a model so the logged out page knows what to display
    var vm = await BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync(model.LogoutId);

    if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
    {
        // delete local authentication cookie
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        // raise the logout event
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLogoutSuccessEvent(User.GetSubjectId(), User.GetDisplayName()));
    }

    // check if we need to trigger sign-out at an upstream identity provider
    if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
    {
        // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
        // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
        // complete our single sign-out processing.
        string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

        // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
    }

    return View("LoggedOut", vm);
}
```

My internal authentication login and logout works just fine by the way. Could someone tell me what I might be missing here?

**Update-1**

Further debugging shows that the value of vm.TriggerExternalSignout in Logout function is always false when logging out. The variable TriggerExternalSignout only appears twice in source code in the entire solution. The first one is in Logout above and the other is in LoggedOutViewModel.cs as shown below:

[image]

The immediate reason why TriggerExternalSignout is false is because the value of the property ExternalAuthenticationScheme is always null. The only place the ExternalAuthenticationScheme get set is in AccountController's BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync function (see screenshot below), which never seems to be invoked (break point never get hit) during login and logout.

[image]

And that's because the value of providerSupportsSignout is false. This makes some sense since Google doesn't support signout, but what should I do to make my logout work?

**Update-2**

I added the logout logic, as nahidf suggested in his answer, in the BuildLoggedOutViewModelAsync function as the following:

[image]

Unfortunately, the logout still doesn't seem to work - I got to the page that says I am logged out after clicking logout from a Google login, but I still get right in by clicking on Google login button when I try to start a new session.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check if `TriggerExternalSignout` is `true` in your case, if not should investigate why is that
- If `TriggerExternalSignout` is already true, try

```
   // delete local authentication cookie
  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

  // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
  wait HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

  // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
```

When we logout from IdentityServer4, it just log user out from our application. It will **NOT** log the user out of their Google account. Google doesn't support third party logout.

**Edit**: For google case `TriggerExternalSignout` is `false` as google doesnt support external logout. [Ref in code](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/AspNetIdentity/host/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L324)

Comment: Thanks nahidf! I did notice that the TriggerExternalSignout value is false and I am currently trying to figure out why...

Comment: what version of Ids4 are you using?

Comment: IdentityServer 4.0.0, .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: nahidf, please seem my new update above - I just added code you recommended (almost in a hardcoded way! just wanted to see the result). But it doesn't seem to make difference. Any thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: It seems the only way I can get a fresh start of a Google authentication session (login page) again is by deleting browsing data using browser.

Comment: Let me check locally, I'll get back to you @Alexu - In the meantime can you update to latest Ids4 just to be sure we use same version

Comment: Thanks @nahidf! As you suggested, I have updated my ids4 to 4.1.1 and retested the logout afterwards. I got the same result.

Comment: I checked locally, when we logout in Ids4 all cookies are deleted and as far as Ids4 know user is logged out. If you check the cookies you will see that they are all cleared. But your google user is still logged in, and Google doesn't support third party logout. This means when Ids4 redirect to google for login it recognize the user as logged in user and doesnt show the login page. This is out of Ids4 scope really. You can add consent on google to get a better understanding of the flow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @nahidf! Really appreciate it! So, if I understand it correctly, this is a common issue with Google and not just me, correct? If so, I may just stop here because I don't have to use Google as my external provider. I may use Microsoft's Identity Platform instead. Do you have recommendations? Meanwhile, I have accepted your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: one thing still puzzles me is that, if I delete browsing data with my browser, then I will be able to get to the Google login page again the next time. That makes me feel it is still about something on my local...

Comment: correct, this is more of how Google flow is designed, not sure if this is an issue. Check [GoogleHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Google/src/GoogleHandler.cs ) code, its not implementing `IAuthenticationSignOutHandler`.  For external login providers I'd say google, twitter and facebook are very well known by end-users. Read about their implementation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) -

Comment: but if you have a custom group of end-users, [here](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers) you can find a good list of providers. I have SalesForce implemented using their lib.

Comment: When Ids4 challenge the external login, the rest is managed by https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth and its out of Ids4 hands. If you check the network tab it would be much more clear to u

Comment: Thanks again @nahidf!